# What's the gtest equivalent of CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN?

Tags: c++, googletest, catch2

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN  // This tells Catch to provide a main() - only do this in one cpp file
```

I cannot find alternative of gtest after googling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [their primer](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md):

> But maybe you think that writing all those `main()` functions is too much work? We agree with you completely and that's why Google Test provides a basic implementation of `main()`. If it fits your needs, then just link your test with `gtest_main` library and you are good to go.

So rather than asking for the library to generate a definition of `main` through a macro, you link in the `gtest_main` library which contains one.

Comment: `target_link_libraries(tests gtest gtest_main)` works fine for my project, thx.